# Prolog improve code to check user input

Tags: list, prolog

I wrote a predicate `take(List,N,Result)` that returns in `Result` the first `N` elements of `List`. I used two predicates to check if `List` is actually a list and if `List` has at least `N` elements, and I want to output the corresponding errors. This is what I did, that works, but it seems not the best style to me, so I'm asking: how can I improve it? In particular the use of `false` and the cut seems a too much complicated way to me, but I'm new to Prolog, so I really don't know and asking here.

```
take(L,N,Result) :-
   checkN(N),
   check(L,N),
   takeaux(L,N,Result).

checkN(N) :-
   (  N > 0
   ;  write('Error N must be positive'),
      false
   ),
   !.

check(L,N) :-
   (  length(L,N1),
      N1 >= N
   ;  write('Error: list has less than '),
      write(N),
      write(' elements'),
      false
   ).
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the widely available, tried and tested predicates [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append) and [`length/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#length) we define:

```
take(List,N,Prefix) :-
   append(Prefix,_,List),
   length(Prefix,N).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- take([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],3,Prefix).
  Prefix = [a,b,c]                   % succeeds, b
; false.                             % terminates universally

?- take([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],N,Prefix).
  N = 0, Prefix = []
; N = 1, Prefix = [a]
; N = 2, Prefix = [a,b]
; N = 3, Prefix = [a,b,c]
; N = 4, Prefix = [a,b,c,d]
; N = 5, Prefix = [a,b,c,d,e]
; N = 6, Prefix = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
; N = 7, Prefix = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
; false.

?- take(List,3,[a,b,c]).
List = [a,b,c|_A].

?- take(List,N,[a,b,c]).
N = 3, List = [a,b,c|_A].
```

Comment: I know it can be done in this way, but my question is about the predicates `check` and `checkN`, forget for a moment the implementation (that I did with predicate `takeaux` in another way and works).

Comment: @rok. Using side-effects for handling errors is troublesome. While `checkN/1` somewhat works, `check/2` needs to be fixed: When running the query `?- check([a,b,c],2).` I get `true ;
Error: list has less than 2 elements
false.`...

Comment: it can easily fixed adding a cut in the same way I did in `checkN` preventing backtrack, but this is my real question? In what other way could I output error messages? My solution seems to me overcomplicated, but I can't find any other solution..any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: @rok. ISO Prolog has a builtin exception handling mechanism that you could use instead (cf.http://www.deransart.fr/prolog/exceptions.html).

Comment: @rok. Consider this part of the GNU-Prolog manual: http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec32